# Writing edit-form component using form from "create" component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to use the form I made in 'create' component in 'edit' component.

There are some properties in data object that i need to populate in edit-component that were empty in create-component, also I want to replace create() method with edit(), method which uses axios to communicate with API.

I am clueless how to proceed with this problem, also I thought this might be a pretty common question to ask but I didn't find any satisfying answer. Is there no way i can replace existing methods in child component? Should I make different component for html form and for relevant methods?

create-component

```
<template>
  <div id="dashboard-form">
    <button class="button modal-button" 
    data-target="#myModal" 
    @click="modalToggle">
      Launch Form
    </button>

    <div class="modal" id="myModal" 
    :class="{'is-active': modalStatus}">
      <div class="modal-backgound"></div>
      <div class="modal-card">
        <header class="modal-card-head">
          <p class="modal-card-title">Fill a new entry</p>
          <button class="delete" 
          aria-label="close" 
          @click="modalToggle">
          </button>
        </header>
        <section class="modal-card-body">
          <form action="post">
            <div class="modal-form" v-if="step === 1">

              <div class="field">
                <label class="label">Parent's Name</label>
                <div class="control">
                  <input type="text" class="input" 
                  placeholder="Enter parent name here" 
                  v-model="parentName" 
                  v-validate="'required'" 
                  name="parentName" 
                  :class="{'is-danger': errors.has('parentName'), 
                  'is-success': parentName!=='' && !errors.has('parentName')}">
                </div>
                <p class="help has-text-left is-danger" 
                v-show="errors.has('parentName')">
                  {{ errors.first('parentName')}}
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <label for="parentContact" class="label">
                  Parent's Contact Number
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                  <input type="tel" class="input" 
                  placeholder="Enter 10 digit mobile number" 
                  v-model="parentContact" 
                  v-validate="{required: true, regex: /^[5-9]\d{9}$/}" 
                  :class="{'is-danger': errors.has('parentContact'), 
                  'is-success': parentContact!=='' && !errors.has('parentContact')}" 
                  name="parentContact">
                </div>
                <p class="help has-text-left is-danger" 
                v-show="errors.has('parentContact')">
                  {{ errors.first('parentContact' )}}
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <label class="label">Student's Name</label>
                <div class="control">
                  <input type="text" class="input is-success" 
                  placeholder="enter student name here" 
                  v-model="studentName"  
                  name="studentName">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <label class="label">Tutor's Name</label>
                <div class="control">
                  <input type="text" class="input" 
                  placeholder="Enter tutor's name here" 
                  v-model="tutorName" 
                  v-validate="'required'" 
                  name="tutorName" 
                  :class="{'is-danger': errors.has('tutorName'), 
                  'is-success': tutorName!=='' && !errors.has('tutorName')}">
                </div>
                <p class="help has-text-left is-danger" 
                v-show="errors.has('tutorName')">
                  {{ errors.first('tutorName')}}
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <label for="tutorContact" class="label">
                  Tutor's Contact Number
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                  <input type="tel" class="input" 
                  placeholder="Enter 10 digit mobile number" 
                  v-model="tutorContact" 
                  v-validate="{required: true, regex: /^[5-9]\d{9}$/}" 
                  :class="{'is-danger': errors.has('tutorContact'), 
                  'is-success': tutorContact!=='' && !errors.has('tutorContact')}" 
                  name="tutorContact">
                </div>
                <p class="help has-text-left is-danger" 
                v-show="errors.has('tutorContact')">
                  {{ errors.first('tutorContact') }}
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <label for="startingDate" class="label">
                  Tuition Started on
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                  <input type="date" class="input" 
                  v-model="startingDate" 
                  v-validate="'required'" 
                  :class="{'is-danger': errors.has('startingDate'), 
                  'is-success': startingDate!='' && !errors.has('startingDate')}" 
                  name="startingDate">
                </div>
                <p class="help has-text-left" 
                v-show="errors.has('startingDate')">
                  {{ errors.first('startingDate') }}
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <label for="sessionDuration" class="label">
                  How long each session lasts(in hours)
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                  <input type="text" class="input" 
                  v-model="sessionDuration" 
                  v-validate="'required'" 
                  :class="{'is-danger': errors.has('sessionDuration'), 
                  'is-success': !errors.has('sessionDuration')}" 
                  name="sessionDuration">
                </div>
                <p class="help has-text-left" v-show="errors.has('sessionDuration')">
                  {{ errors.first('sessionDuration') }}
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <label for="sessionsMonth" class="label">
                  Number of sessions in a month.
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                  <input type="number" class="input" 
                  v-model="sessionsMonth" 
                  v-validate="'required'" 
                  :class="{'is-danger': errors.has('sessionsMonth'), 
                  'is-success': !errors.has('sessionsMonth')}" 
                  name="sessionsMonth">
                </div>
                <p class="help has-text-left" 
                v-show="errors.has('sessionsMonth')">
                  {{ errors.first('sessionsMonth') }}
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <label for="fees" class="label">
                  Fees Charged from Parents
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                  <input type="number" class="input" 
                  v-model="fees" v-validate="'required|min_value:500'" 
                  :class="{'is-danger': errors.has('fees'), 
                  'is-success': !errors.has('fees')}" 
                  name="fees">
                </div>
                <p class="help has-text-left" 
                v-show="errors.has('fees')">
                  {{ errors.first('fees') }}
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <label for="commission" class="label">
                  How much commission is being charged?
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                  <input type="number" class="input" 
                  v-model="commission" 
                  v-validate="'required|min_value:0|max_value:50'" 
                  :class="{'is-danger': errors.has('commission'), 
                  'is-success': !errors.has('commission')}" 
                  name="commission">
                </div>
                <p class="help has-text-left" 
                v-show="errors.has('commission')">
                  {{ errors.first('commission') }}
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <label for="coordinator" class="label">Coordinator</label>
                <div class="control">
                  <div class="select" 
                  :class="{'is-success': coordinator!=='', 
                  'is-danger': coordinator==='' && coordinatorIsFocused}">
                    <select name="coordinator" v-model="coordinator" 
                    @focus.once="coordinatorToggle">
                      <option selected disabled>Name of Coordinator</option>
                      <option value="seth">Himanshu(Seth)</option>
                      <option value="hk">Himanshu(HK)</option>
                      <option value="anuj">Anuj</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p class="help has-text-left" 
                v-show="coordinator==='' && coordinatorIsFocused">
                  Selecting one of the option is required
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="field">
                <label for="paymentMode" class="label"></label>
                <div class="control">
                  <div class="select" 
                  :class="{'is-success': paymentMode!=='', 
                  'is-danger': paymentMode==='' && paymentModeIsFocused}">
                    <select name="paymentMode" v-model="paymentMode"
                    @focus.once="paymentModeToggle">
                      <option disabled selected>Mode of Payment</option>
                      <option value="cash">Cash</option>
                      <option value="paytm">PayTM</option>
                      <option value="bank seth">Bank Seth</option>
                      <option value="bank anuj">Bank Anuj</option>
                      <option value="kotak">Kotak</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p class="help has-text-left" 
                v-show="paymentMode==='' && paymentModeIsFocused">
                  Selecting one of the option is required
                </p>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-form" v-if="step === 2">

              <div class="field">
                <p class="has-text-left">In which standard student is studing?</p>
                <div class="control">
                  <div class="select" 
                  :class="{'is-success': standard!='', 
                  'is-danger': standard==='' && standardIsFocused}">
                    <select v-model="standard" 
                    @focus.once="standardToggle()" 
                    @change="emptySubjects()">
                      <option value="pre-primary">Pre-Primary</option>
                      <option value="1">Standard 1</option>
                      <option value="2">Standard 2</option>
                      <option value="3">Standard 3</option>
                      <option value="4">Standard 4</option>
                      <option value="5">Standard 5</option>
                      <option value="6">Standard 6</option>
                      <option value="7">Standard 7</option>
                      <option value="8">Standard 8</option>
                      <option value="9">Standard 9</option>
                      <option value="10">Standard 10</option>
                      <option value="11-sci">Standard 11 - Science</option>
                      <option value="11-com">Standard 11 - Commerce</option>
                      <option value="11-art">Standard 11 - Arts</option>
                      <option value="12-sci">Standard 12 - Science</option>
                      <option value="12-com">Standard 12 - Commerce</option>
                      <option value="12-art">Standard 12 - Arts</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p class="help has-text-left is-danger" 
                v-show="standard==='' && standardIsFocused">
                  Selecting one of the option is required.
                </p>
              </div>

              <p>Which subject(s) does the student need help with?</p>
              <div class="field">
                <div class="control" v-for="(subject,index) in subjectListFinal" :key="index">
                  <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" :value="subject" v-model="subjects" v-validate="'required'" name="subjects">
                      {{subject}}
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <p class="help has-text-left is-danger" 
              v-show="errors.has('subjects')">
                Select atleast one subject.
              </p>
            </div>

          </form>
        </section>

        <footer class="modal-card-foot">
          <div class="field is-grouped">
            <button class="button is-link" 
            @click="prev" v-show="step===2">
              Previous
            </button>
            <button class="button is-link" 
            @click="next" v-show="step===1">
              Next
            </button>
            <button class="button is-link" 
            @click="validateBeforeSubmit" v-show="step===2">
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>  
        </footer>

      </div>
      <label class="modal-close is-large" @click="modalToggle"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'DashboardForm',
  data () {
    return {
      modalStatus: false,
      standardIsFocused: false,
      coordinatorIsFocused: false,
      paymentModeIsFocused: false,
      step: 1,
      parentName: '',
      parentContact: '',
      studentName: '',
      tutorName: '',
      tutorContact: '',
      startingDate: '',
      sessionDuration: '1',
      sessionsMonth: 24,
      fees: null,
      commission: null,
      coordinator: '',
      paymentMode: '',
      standard: '',
      subjects: [],
      prePrimarySubjects: [
        'Abacus',
        'Handwriting Basics',
        'English Phonetics',
        'English',
        'KG Academics'
      ],
      standard1To5Subjects: [
        'All Subjects',
        'Vedic Maths',
        'Mathematics',
        'Science',
        'English',
        'Hindi',
        'Environmental Studies',
        'Mathematics-Science (Combo)',
        'Handwriting (English/Hindi)'
      ],
      standard6To10Subjects:[
        'Mathematics',
        'Science',
        'Computer Science',
        'English',
        'Hindi',
        'Social Science',
        'Sanskrit',
        'Environmental Studies',
        'French',
        'German',
        'Spanish',
        'Mathematics-Science (Combo)',
        'Olympiad Maths/Science'
      ],
      standard11To12ArtsSubjects: [
        'Geography',
        'History',
        'Political Science',
        'Humanities',
        'English',
        'Psychology',
        'Computer Science/Information Practices'
      ],
      standard11To12CommerceSubjects: [
        'Accounts',
        'Business Studies',
        'Economics',
        'Mathematics',
        'English',
        'Psychology',
        'Computer Science/Information Practices'
      ],
      standard11To12ScienceSubjects: [
        'Mathematics',
        'Physics',
        'Chemistry',
        'English',
        'PCB Combo',
        'PCM Combo',
        'Computer Science/Information Practices',
        'Competitive Exam Preparation'
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    modalToggle() {
      this.modalStatus = !this.modalStatus
    },
    prev() {
      this.step--
    },
    next() {
      this.coordinatorToggle()
      this.paymentModeToggle()
      this.$validator.validate('parentName', this.parentName)
      this.$validator.validate('parentContact', this.parentContact)
      this.$validator.validate('tutorName', this.tutorName)
      this.$validator.validate('tutorContact', this.tutorContact)
      this.$validator.validate('startingDate', this.startingDate)
      this.$validator.validate('sessionDuration', this.sessionDuration)
      this.$validator.validate('sessionsMonth', this.sessionsMonth)
      this.$validator.validate('fees', this.fees)
      this.$validator.validate('commission', this.commission).then(() => {
        if(!this.errors.any() && this.coordinator!=='' && this.paymentMode!==''){
          this.step++
        }
      })
    },
    validateBeforeSubmit() {
      this.$validator.validateAll().then(() => {
        if(!this.errors.any()) {
          this.addQuery()
          this.modalToggle()
        }
      })
    },
    standardToggle() {
      this.standardIsFocused = true
    },
    coordinatorToggle() {
      this.coordinatorIsFocused = true
    },
    paymentModeToggle() {
      this.paymentModeIsFocused = true
    },
    emptySubjects() {
      this.subjects = []
    },
    addQuery() {
      axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/dashboard/',
        data: {
          parent_name: this.parentName,
          parent_contact: this.parentContact,
          student_name: this.studentName,
          tutor_name: this.tutorName,
          tutor_contact: this.tutorContact,
          standard: this.standard,
          subject: this.subjects,
          starting_date: this.startingDate,
          session_month: this.sessionsMonth,
          session_duration: this.sessionDuration,
          fees: this.fees,
          commission: this.commission,
          coordinator: this.coordinator,
          mode_payment: this.paymentMode
        }
      }).then(() =>{
        this.parentName = '',
        this.subjects = [],
        this.parentContact = '',
        this.studentName = '',
        this.tutorName = '',
        this.tutorContact = '',
        this.standard = '',
        this.startingDate = '',
        this.sessionsMonth = 24,
        this.sessionDuration = '1',
        this.fees = null,
        this.commission = null,
        this.coordinator = '',
        this.paymentMode = '',
        this.step = 1
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  },
  computed: {
    subjectListFinal: function() {
      if (this.standard==='pre-primary'){
        return this.prePrimarySubjects
      }
      else if (this.standard==='1'||this.standard==='2'||this.standard==='3'||this.standard==='4'||this.standard==='5') {
        return this.standard1To5Subjects
      }
      else if (this.standard==='6'||this.standard==='7'||this.standard==='8'||this.standard==='9'||this.standard==='10') {
        return this.standard6To10Subjects
      }
      else if (this.standard==='11-sci'||this.standard==='12-sci') {
        return this.standard11To12ScienceSubjects
      }
      else if (this.standard==='11-com'||this.standard==='12-com') {
        return this.standard11To12CommerceSubjects
      }
      else if (this.standard==='11-art'||this.standard==='12-art') {
        return this.standard11To12ArtsSubjects
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: could you show your tried work?

Comment: are using Vue.js via CDN ot Vue Cli

Comment: I am using vue-cli, what i tried was including create-component to edit-component and tried to bind mentioned properties in the edit-component, it didn't work and now I am completely clueless how to proceed. I'll try to follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49233903/post-form-empty-data and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307357/how-to-create-a-reusable-form-vue-component discussions to see where they lead me to

Comment: ok, i undertstand that you want to get your code to be reusable, you have two components with same properties (props,data, computed ...)?

Comment: Yes both edit and create should have the same properties. I think I asked the question without giving it much of thought myself so that I can come up with something specific. This question seems to be a lot broader than I originally thought. Thank you for looking into it anyways.

Comment: so, provide me the content of one component (edit for example) and the content of parent one and i will give you a solution

Comment: Included my whole "create component", I want to use this to make "edit component". while replacing addQuery() method with editQuery() component, while populating empty data properties with data I'll get from getQuery() method